# Enable forward button while disabling browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, back

I disabled browser back button using the following code on load of page

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
};
```

Code is working fine.I am not able to proceed for previous pages. But forward button is also disabled. I have to enable forward button on the page.

Comment: How about this: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-Functionality-using-JavaScript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing to update url manually by using **history.pushState**. If you use **history.pushState**, it clears forward state's history.

Hence `window.history.forward()` returns undefined. So you cannot go to forward direction.

Kindly use warning instead of disabling back button,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
return "some text"
};
```